# what is the difference between a use case diagram and a uml diagram?

Tags: uml

Is there any difference between uml diagram and a use case diagram ? Since both the diagrams are made differently but both show the same information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with the UML and use case.

UML contains different diagrams and Use case is one of it. Use Case diagram defines Behavioural component of Software Design i.e. Actor communicating with the system through Task - Use Case.

UML also contains Structural diagrams as well as - such as Class Diagram.

From what I can understand UML is a superset and USE case is subset.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the same thing that I know yet my project partner is not ready and has constructed separate uae case diagram and a separte uml diagram. Thank you

Comment: A separate uml diagram - that is fine however you can ask them what it means - whether a flow chart, state diagram, class diagram or something. Your project partner may like to speak the same language as you do; nothing is wrong in getting any clarification.

Comment: Is it necessary that every process in a dfd should always go to a sink ?? for eg: i have a chat module made using application state in my project and i am not storing the chats in the database. will chat be shown in the dfd ? also i have used session state to fetch the uid of the user .. there is flow of data but will it be shown in the  dfd ?

Answer (score 0):

UML stands for Unified modeling language, It provides a set of graphical notations and diagrams that help describe, design, and communicate the various aspects of a system. UML diagrams can represent different perspectives of a software system, including its structure, behavior, interactions, and architecture.

In Use case diagram is a specific type of UML diagram that focuses on representing the interactions between actors (users or external systems) and a system. It illustrates the functional requirements of a system by showing the various use cases (or actions) that actors can perform and how they are related.